# How to preload javascript, images, css and/or misc files?

Tags: jquery, preload

Currently I'm working on a huge project that involves thousands of lines of CSS, JavaScript and a bunch of images. Minifying CSS style sheets and JavaScript files with added compression helps a lot, but it still isn't perfect.

For preloading images in CSS stylesheets, I have found a bunch of plugins, including here on stackoverflow. However, since there are a lot of jQuery and JavaScript libraries - preloading just CSS images in stylesheets doesn't help my cause at all. Is there a way to preload the CSS files themselves, along with images found in those files, and JavaScript libraries in one go? I would use such a feature after confirming user credentials, and after preloading the required content redirecting users to the inner content.

Also: I could easily provide an array of files needed for preloading, without having JavaScript to parse any files.

Comment: if you are usingany server side framework, then you can apply staticContent cache. for more info http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache

Comment: A big part of the libraries are created on the fly with Java, and almost 80% of them change after a user session has ended. It's a very stupid system, and I have the *honors* of trying to make everything work :/

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at using the appcache to cache resources. That will speed things up for modern browsers, though won't help you with older ones. There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/).

I'm guessing most of your page size comes from images. You might try spriting your images and using gzip, which is supported by even older browsers (IE 5.5+ for example).

Comment: I'll be sure to try this out. However there are a bunch of clients who won't upgrade their browsers, and I'm stuck with almost a 10mb page load :/

Comment: Not only images, there are a bunch of proprietary JavaScript libraries I *HAVE* to use. The system is insanely old, the only addition I made was adding jQuery to ease the amount of new code written for the basic UI. The servers where moved from local to cloud, and the loading times are insane.. That's why I'd like to preload everything during the login process, it would be more clear than having a broken HTML page while everything loads..

Comment: are you sure that downloading the files is the bottleneck? With all that CSS and javascript, the page will probably take a long time to render

Comment: Yes, because the internet connection is really slow, thus it takes up to a minute to load everything. The system was local before the move to cloud, and the load on the browsers wasn't that significant.